# How does the document.forms name selector for inputs work in JavaScript DOM?

Tags: javascript, meteor, selector

In Meteor's todo app tutorial, there is this example :

```
  Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-task": function (event) {
      // Prevent default browser form submit
      event.preventDefault();

      // Get value from form element
      var text = event.target.text.value;

      [...]
    }
  });
```

This is the related HTML :

```
  <form class="new-task">
    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" />
  </form>
```

What surprises me is the `event.target.text.value` is a valid selector, although `text` is not a property of the `event.target` object.

Can someone explain to me why the is valid?

Comment: Could you justify the down vote?! 
Explain to me why is this a valid selector instead of downvoting you DA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of your code snippet, `event.target` is a reference to the form.

`event.target.text` is a reference to the form element with the name "text", which is passed to the callback in the collection of inputs within the form element.

> **Note**:
>   This is a unique attribute of forms, for backwards-compatibility with the pre-DOM `document.forms` collection, which references forms and their input elements by name rather than by id.  For example, you can reference the search form input on this page using `document.forms.search.q`

Comment: So in Javascript, one can query elements by `name` using the dot notation? I tried but it didn't work. I selected the form element in the console doing `var form = document.getElementsByClassName("new-task");`, and then `var input = form.text;`. But this returns `undefined`. So the dot notation doesn't seem to be normalized to select elements by name from their parents.

Comment: Edited answer with an explanation

Comment: @AlexandreBourlier - `document.getElementsByClassName("new-task")` returns an array.  try `document.getElementsByClassName("new-task")[0].text` and it should work fine

Comment: Many thanks. I had tried withthe `[0]` notation but must have inserted a typo somewhere, has it didn't return anything. 

Many thanks for the explanation. I now understand this is a special treatment for forms and their named children. That sounds less of an alien notation to me!